# How do I associate one piece of content with another in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I have two folders, one full of images and another full of text files.

How do I add a property to the text file that allows the user to pick an item from the image folder? (I know how to add basic properties like numbers and dates using aspects.)

I already tried these, but Share renders them as read-only boxes.

```
            <property name="my:propQName">
                <title>QName Property</title>
                <type>d:qname</type>
            </property>

            <property name="my:propNodeRef">
                <title>Node Reference Property </title>
                <type>d:noderef</type>
            </property>

            <property name="my:propPath">
                <title>Path Property </title>
                <type>d:path</type>
            </property>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an [association](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide#Peer_.28Non-Child.29_Associations):

```
      <associations>
        <association name="my:relatedImage">
           <source>
              <mandatory>true</mandatory>
              <many>false</many>
           </source>
           <target>
              <class>my:imageType</class>
              <mandatory>true</mandatory>
              <many>false</many>
           </target>
        </association>
     </associations>
```

This will render by default as a picker. You can always [configure the picker](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms#association.ftl) as usual in `share-config-custom.xml`.

---

EDIT: [official documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/metadata-model-assoc.html) on associations

Comment: Do you have any actual documentation on this? The link you provided didn't explain anything.

Comment: Also, what is "my:imageType". I don't see that listed anywhere.

Comment: The `my:imageType` is just a placeholder for anything you might have in your repository, change it with `cm:content` or whatever you like.