# Obtaining path of associated documents in custom model in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I have an association in custom model in alfresco as has been mentioned in the post:
[How do I associate one piece of content with another in Alfresco?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237145/how-do-i-associate-one-piece-of-content-with-another-in-alfresco/23740764?noredirect=1#comment36497323_23740764)

For properties, to get the name of the property I am using:
var model = document.properties["sc:itemNo"];

How can I obtain the name and path where this image resides in the repository, using JavaScript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `document` has an association named `sc:sampleAssoc` and there is at least one association exsting for that node, you  will get its full qname path like so:

```
var qNameOfAssocatiatedNode = document.assocs["sc:sampleAssoc"][0].qnamePath;
```

Be clear though that there  may be more than one node at that path.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can see the name of the associated document now. If I do: var qNameOfAssocatiatedNode = document.assocs["sc:sampleAssoc"][0].url;                           I get this url /d/d/workspace/SpacesStore/dbdeccd0-c647-4182-9a1f-07d3a93b8973/ppimage.png. How can I get the downloadable url, by clicking on which the document can be accessed?

Comment: Append node.downloadUrl to the url of your alfresco repository. Have a look at  http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/URL_Addressability#DownloadContentServlet  for  the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did this and it worked for the url: var urlStr = document.assocs["sc:relatedDocuments"][0].url;
var imageUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/share/proxy/alfresco/api/node/content/"+urlStr.substring(4);